# Extract multiple GSM expression values from multiple GEO file without pulling the whole GEO data to local computer

Tags: r, web-crawler, bioinformatics

I want to extract some of GSM expression data from each GEO matrix, and I have a lot GEO matrix to look into.

I am thinking to crawler GEO data online and only extract GSM sample of interests for saving the local memory and speed up the time, but due to limited experiences in web crawling I have no idea how to write it..

The GEO data is dirty and looks like:

```
!Series_title   "Novel biomarkers for high grade T-cell lymphoma"
!Series_geo_accession   "GSE20874"
!Series_status  "Public on Mar 01 2011"
!Series_submission_date "Mar 14 2010"
!Series_last_update_date    "Mar 22 2012"
!Series_summary "Mature NK and T-cell lymphomas are occasionally encountered in Asia but are very rare in Western populations. In part due to its rarity, little is known about this group of neoplasms, and despite being rather different disease entities, they are all treated similarly but with diverse clinical outcomes. Novel biomarkers (at both the genetic and protein levels) are needed to resolve diagnostic difficulties, improve prognostication and develop targeted therapies.....

         |GSM1|GSM2|GSM3|.......|GSMn|
--------------------------------------
sample 1 |3.4 |3.6 | 8.9|.......|7.9 |
--------------------------------------
sample 2 |...........................|
--------------------------------------
sample 3.......
```

If I only interested in looking columns of GSM1, GSM3, and GSM7, how could I get these floating numbers without pulling the whole data to my local computer? Thanks!

Comment: First, this question is probably better suited for [Bioinformatics SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/). Second, most NCBI data repositories provide APIs, standalone tools and libraries for programmatic access, and often supports the development of packages in scripting languages for programmatic access.  For example, here is [the GEO documentation on programmatic access](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/geo_paccess.html).

Answer (score 2):

Not the most helpful answer. But there is a nice package called GEOquery which might help you out! I has a range of tools for downloading and manipulating GSE, GDS, and GSM objects from GEO.

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GEOquery/inst/doc/GEOquery.html

You could also combine it with ExpressionSet subsetting tools from Biobase to isolate the exact samples you want.

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html